# GETTING the VALUE of SUM()

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting an error in the while loop below that says "Cannot Implicitly convert type 'float' to 'string'".

```
try
{    
    string ab = "select Sum(amount) from matriculationfee ";
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(ab, con);
    SqlDataReader myReader;

    con.Open();
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {          
        txtbalance.Text=(((float)myReader["amount"]).ToString());
        //It Says here that it Cannot Implicity convert type 'float' to 'string
    }
}

catch (SqlException w)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Erro!" + w.Message);
}
```

Please Help me.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you getting an error message? You need to describe what you're trying to do and what isn't working.

Comment: I cannot get the value of the Sum()

Comment: This is the error //It Says here that it Cannot Implicity convert type 'float' to 'string

Comment: Why are you casting it to float in the first place?

Comment: Try `myReader.GetFloat(0)` or `myReader.GetFloat(myReader.GetOrdinal("amount"))`.

Comment: While you are writing your questions, you will always see a preview below it that shows you what your question is going to look like. Please make sure everything is formatted properly before posting your question. Your code was a mess, so I didn't notice the comment. Also, it helps to describe your question before the code so people know what to look for instead of just being presented with a block of code and having to hunt for the question.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to name the column you are returning:

```
string ab = "select Sum(amount) AS amount from matriculationfee ";
```

Then I suggest you simplify your conversion code:

```
var amount = float.Parse(myReader["amount"]);
txtbalance.Text= amount.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alias the resulting sum like so:

```
string ab = "select SUM(amount) AS total from matriculationfee ";
```

Then refer to it like so:

```
var amount = myReader.GetFloat("total");
txtbalance.Text= amount.ToString();
```